# woocommerce shipping based on product ranges

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

Can we use this formula for woocommerce shipping based on product ranges? if yes help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use Table Rate Shipping Plugin: Check This https://wordpress.org/plugins/table-rate-shipping-for-woocommerce/

and then follow this doc: [Check this](https://bluesteelesolutions.com/woocommerce-quantity-based-shipping/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the table rate shipping plugin and configure it for the above formula. With the plugin, you can set shipping rate based on quantity along with weight and price.

You can use [this plugin](https://www.pluginhive.com/product/woocommerce-table-rate-shipping-pro-plugin/). Or if you are looking for advance automation you can use SaaS-based [WooCommerce shipping soluction](https://www.storepep.com/ups-shipping-with-woocommerce-using-storepep/).